# Setup Ubuntu Server on laptop Virtualbox without ethernet

Tags: networking, server, wireless, virtualbox

Hi I am new to linux and Ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS according to this [guide](https://github.com/xtuple/xtuple-admin-utility/wiki/Steps-to-Install-Ubuntu) on my HP Zbook 15u g4 on a Virtualbox. During the installation, there was a screen that prompt me to enter 3 IP addresses, but I have skipped that. I usually use Wifi to connect to internet and I don't have access to ethernet cable. Where should I start?

Thanks.

Comment: The three IPs, likely gateway, subnet and address, are optional. Whether you use wifi or ethernet is irrelevant, as Ubuntu will only see virtual hardware. I'd start with stating what you want next. What exactly you want help with. As is, the question is rather vague.

Comment: I need to setup the internet to get update.

Comment: In the settings of the VM (change) on the Network tab you have to change Network Adapter to e.g. NAT. Than reboot the VM. Now it should use the hosts internet connection. Usually you use bridged but setting up WiFi on an Ubuntu server without GUI is not that trivial. The 3 IPs you where asked would have been 1. Your Server's IP 2. The netmask (e.g. 255.255.255.0) and the Gateways IP (e.g. of your router or the host depending on your network adapter settings

Comment: Thanks derHugo, after setting to NAT, it's working now, I can do `sudo apt-get update` to get update from the internet.